# Searching over multiple entries in logn time

Tags: java, binary-search, time-complexity

I have to write a program which create's an address book that can provide search functionality on multiple fields, with a large number of records. Binary search is an option but the tricky part is that the user can search over any of the four fields (firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, City). So there is no particular column over which I can sort the list. The program should also return search results in logarithmic time.
Right now I have created a generic arraylist<contacts> which contains all the four fields.
Can anyone suggest what would be the best way to get the search to work in log time.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of problem that DBMS are made for.  They handle storing the large amounts of data, they handle indexing on multiple fields.  And the best thing is, you don't even have to worry about it after setting up your indexes.

Answer (score 3):

One approach that is somewhat memory-intensive would be to build four parallel binary search trees (or four `Set`s whose comparators compare one field at a time).  That way, you can do a search on any tree to find a node with a particular field in O(lg n) time.

Comment: Some of the files I would be reading contains over 350,000 records. So maintaining 4 parallel trees would eat up all my memory. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a data base and define the indexes you need.

If you can't use a db, then sort and search. You can sort in O(log n) time on whichever field you need. Then you can search in O(log n) time on the sorted field. Not the way to do it in a production environment, but as an assignment, you can claim, "Total time complexity: O(log n)."

Comment: This is a project. The only resources I can use are CSV files, to read the data and java collections to store, sort and search.

Comment: I updated my answer with a non-db approach. P.S. Tagging assignments as "homework" avoids this kind of confusion. :-)

Comment: :) My professor turned out to be smarter than that. I should have also mentioned that he said we can initialize the list just once. That is, whatever sorting has to be done will have to be done during the initialization phase. Once the user starts searching over any of the records, the program can just do a search. No sorting allowed after initialization. Sorry for the lack of detail in my first post. But do you have any suggestions on how I can approach this problem?

Comment: Are you restricted to a single list? What other data structures can you use?

Comment: No other restrictions on what data structures I can use. I have been provided with CSV data files. I can use any kind of structure to hold the data as long as I do the sorting during initialization and the partial string search (begins with...") returns all possible matching values in O(log n)

Comment: Wow. Partial string matches? This assignment just keeps growing! Let me think on this.

Comment: Okay, after thinking about this, I think this problem is poorly defined. If a query could return all n records, it can't possibly execute in O(log n) time; just copying the record ids to a results array would be an O(n) operation.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I guess he needed the average case scenario to return in at least log n. I guess I can try keeping four parallel binary trees as suggested above. It would be memory intensive but would return the results quicker.

Comment: Sorting isn't O(log n), it's O(n log n)*. Therefore sorting it over and over on the fly doesn't help.

* For comparison sorts. This is slightly complicated by Radix sort but this still wouldn't make it O(log n).

Comment: @Jatin - If you need to do prefix searching, you are probably better off with four [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (prefix indices) rather than regular indices. @MGwynne - You're right. I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Store it using 4 trees and an arraylist.

The 4 trees should only consider the indices. You shouldn't have to store the whole of each string in the tree, just enough of the string to distinguish it from the rest of the strings (i.e. store characters at the nodes and you get to a leaf when you have enough of a prefix to identify the string(s)). You can be a bit clever by annotating your tree with "skip n letters" nodes so you don't store internal nodes when all strings in that sub-tree are equal on the next n letters.

The arraylist then stores the records.

At the leaves of the trees you just store an index into the arraylist.

If you do this right, you use 350,000 * 2 * 4 (bytes for integer) + X ~= 3MB + X where X is the size of your file, surely your system has that much? You can even leave the data in the file and index into the file.